# Using AngjularJS with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap

I want to refactor an OLD legacy application and give it a new feel... so, I want to use Twitter Boostrap for the UI... I've also been playing around a lot with AngularJS... is it common place to use them in conjunction with one another? Is it even the correct question to ask? I've done about an hour's worth of "googling" on the subject and I see a lot of people using the CSS-portion of bootstrap with Angular, however, do I gain anything (or lose anything) by also including the bootstrap .js portion, as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That all depends. Are you going to use the UI widgets as built by Bootstrap or are you going to use AngularJS-ish versions? Fortunately, someone has addressed that: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS utilize web front end technologies (HTML & CSS) and don't abstract them out with extra layer like what other frameworks; therefor you require a strong web front end framework to work with AngularJS providing standard language, will supported framework and a plug and play responsive implementation.

let's consider the other options that works with AngularJS:

1. not using a framework and create everything from scratch: unless you are a very good web developer with a strong team supporting you and plenty of time; avoid this option, this requires long experience and knowledge in web technologies not to mention compatibility handling, responsive implementation.
2. using other frameworks: i don't see many reasons not to go for other frameworks like [ZURB Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) other than personal taste and good support; bootstrap is wildly used now and well supported, and you can find plenty of snippets and template websites online such as [Bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/).

bottom-line using bootstrap with AngularJS would definitely increase your productivity and chances of success, reduce cost and implementation effort, personally i think the mix is priceless.